# Why do feature modules have to export common dependencies in AngularJS

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I have been reading this tutorial on creating a feature module : https://johnpapa.net/introducing-angular-modules-feature-modules-2/.

In this tutorial `FormsModule` is imported by `shared.module.ts` and then exported. Why is that ?

Also why does `shared.module.ts` also exports `CommonModule`. Why is that?

Also does this mean that I have to export all my SharedModule's imports ?

Best regards

Comment: Well, the shared module is a module to be shared among all modules if needed. Therefore, it can be used on other modules without you having to especify it on module declaration.

Answer (score 1):

So that the importing module doesn't need to import them as well.
I assume that using that module usually requires using `CommonModule` and `FormsModule` anyway and this way just adding `ShardModule` to `imports: []` will do.

Comment: Why would I have to export them then ? When importing "SharedModule" shouldn't the DI thingy know that it depends on the FormsModule and make it available to the SharedModule ? What does any module importing the SharedModule care about the FormsModule which is an internal dependency of the SharedModule ?

Comment: If it's only an internal dependency, then you shouldn't export it. Exporting it is only for convenience of the user when it is expected that `SharedModule` is always used toghether with `CommonModule` and `FormsModule` so that the user only needs 1 import instead of 3.

Comment: But why would the user need to import CommonModule and FormsModule when importing SharedModule ? They are SharedModule's dependencies ? Shouldn't the DI automatically import them without me having to explicitly "export" them ? Does this mean also that I have to export all my SharedModule's "imports"

Comment: There is no "need". I said "for convenience".

Comment: So importing SharedModule will work even if I delete SharedModule's export statement ?

Comment: Sure. But if you uses features contained in these exported modules directly, you'll have to add them to `imports: [...]` explicitly.